# How to delete an inconsistent range of text from a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Data is copied from a .txt file into Excel.

I need to remove data that always starts with "Date :" and ends with "Allow N".
This data can include dates, numbers, and empty cells.
This data always spans from cell A1 to cell J53.
This text can sometimes pop up further down the A column and span until a lower J column. How much further down the text appears is not consistent.

I figured out how to delete the first 53 lines. The tricky part is the inconsistency at which the other instances of the data pops up.

How would I delete every instance of "Date : ... Allow N"?

Comment: A screenshot of your data, along with your current code, would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this to be dynamic at all? might be worth looking into for the future, but for now, lets roll with the block you specified.

```
Public Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("TheWorkSheetName")
    
Dim myDeleteBlock As Range
    Set myDeleteBlock = ws.Range("A1:J53")
    
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    For Each aCell In myDeleteBlock.Cells
        
        Dim stringToRemove As String
            stringToRemove = "Allow N"
            
        Dim aCellsValue As String
        
        aCellsValue = aCell.Value
        

        If Not InStr(aCellsValue, stringToRemove) = 0 Then
            aCell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next
```

End Sub

This is a cheating kind of way to do it, because the data you want to discard contains "Allow N" by far easier than parsing a date from the string, and then discarding if its recognised as a date. There'd be more process calls involved, and you'd still have to loop anyway.

InStr is a function that searches inside the left-given string, for the right-given string, and returns a number > 0 if the condition is true.

To Expand, you'd want to make this dynamic.

you could to a usedRange count, so the Range object you declare, is actually the sheets used range.

Then from there, for each cell in workbook.worksheet.usedrange.rows.count.

Comment: Help me edit this please its a nightmare lol